# How can I paramaterise a T4 template to produce the same structure for different types?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, t4

I am building a T4 template that will build a POCO from a LINQ to SQL entity, but right now it produces one POCO file based on one L2S entity.  How can I reuse this remplate to iterate through all L2S entities and produce a POCO for each one, or for any chosen one?

Comment: I would love to see what you have so far -- I need to do something similar myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com. You may want to read the tutorial articles that show you how to generate multiple files and check out the L2S generator.

Oleg